# Unresponsive Script window pops up all the time now. Why and what to do?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, javascript

I don't know that it's for the exact same script each time, it may be.

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.
>
> Script: chrome://messenger/content/folderPane.js:721

This is in association with Thunderbird I think.

This doesn't just happen after I've stepped away for a long time. It happens every time I click on anything. Things keep running that I'm clicking on.

Just before this started as a constant problem, I was looking at addons etc, and something in Thunderbird deactivated an old or expired JavaScript. I clicked on the update for that and after a while I found the best choice on the list and clicked download.

I don't know that anything happened with that and I moved away from addons etc area. The unresponsive script window started coming back all the time. Every time I clicked on something in Thunderbird and sometimes with Firefox. I turned off Firefox and restarted, but it didn't change. Shut down Firefox and computer restarted didn't change. The unresponsive script window is persistent now.

Comment: Any of these installed recently `Folderpane`, `CompactHeader`, `JunQuilla`, `MoreFunctionsForAdressBook`, `MRTechToolKit`,`RemoveDuplicateMessages`? Folderpane might have been installed separately or together with another add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Generally unresponsive scripts are caused due to buggy add-ons, or when add-ons are being used in an unintended manner.

The most common solution is to disable all of your add-ons and enable them one by one with intervals of usage until you find out the one causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Firefox 37.0.2 this is my way of fixing this.

From **tools** menu, select **addons** and then, on addons page, select **extensions**

Disable all extensions and verify that the problem does not occur anymore.
Re-enable one extension at a time and detect the one that causes the problem.